# Adding Additional Fields to a sObject in Apex, (just for manipulation)

Tags: apex, soql, json, sobject

I'm working with some *complicated* queries, and I need to send over http, the sObject in turn, but I can't make queries with more than 1 level of depth in the SOQL, so I am working with separated queries, then composing the sObjects, (or at least that is what I try), so I can created a full `json` for when I send the `http request`, but It raises an exception 
like this

```
System.SObjectException: Invalid field Object_A for Object_B
```

May be I'm doing it wrong, but I am trying to add the field as if it where a *regular map or sobject*

```
// meta is a metadata object with a fixed query string
// sidWhere is a string with the ID and the quotation marks just to append to the query
string soql_main   = meta.SOQL_Fields__c + ' WHERE Id = ' + sidWhere;
sObject[] join1;
string soql_join_1 = meta.SOQL_Join_1__c + sidWhere; 
string sObjTypeName1;
join_1 = database.query(soql_join_1);
sObjTypeName1 = join_1.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
main.put(sObjTypeName1, join_1); // Here it throws the exception
```

So, what would be a better way to do this composition I say, It's just adding one `field` to the `main` sobject, that contains the list of sobjects from the query in `soql_join_1`.

Any Ideas?

> Edit
>
> Let's say I have an ObjectB that It's related to ObjectA via a lookup, that means ObjectB has a field pointing to ObjectA.
>   Now I want to get Object A and all the records that point to it of the ObjectB, but ObjectB also have records pointing to it of the type ObjectC, So I need to pull ObjectA with `id = sid`, and this will pull up all records ObjectB and does will pull their corresponding ObjectC's
>
> The problem is that, when I try to make a Double nested query from the ObjectA table, turns out to be unallowed, so I did a query to pull up, Exclusivly ObjectA fields, and another one different that gets a list of all the ObjectB objects, that relate to ObjectA, and their children. NOW I want to manipulate the sOjbectA so It contains the list of ObjectB's that came out from a different query. Because I need to send it outside as a Json.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking is, given a variable `objectA` of type `Object_A__c` and `objectB` of type `Object_B__c`, which have a relationship to one another, how to reconstruct the object network in memory as if it had issued from a SOQL query. (Even if, as it sounds, you could not actually issue a SOQL query for an object network this complex).

When you query a relationship in SOQL - let's say that `Object_B__c` has a lookup relationship to `Object_A__c` called `Parent__c` - you do it from child to parent like this:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Parent__c, Parent__r.Name, Parent__r.Some_Other_Field__c
FROM Object_B__c
WHERE some_criteria_are_true
```

An `Object_B__c` instance coming from this query will have `Parent__c` populated (assuming it's got the relationship established) with an `Id` value, and it will *also* have the property `Parent__r` populated, with an sObject instance of type `Object_A__c`.

We can synthesize that structure using the method [`putSobject()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#!):

```
 Object_A__c objectA = [SELECT .... FROM Object_A__c WHERE ...];
 Object_B__c objectB = [SELECT .... FROM Object_B__c WHERE ...];

 objectB.putSobject('Parent__r', objectA);
```

If we want the lookup field populated too, we'd have to also issue

```
objectB.put('Parent__c', objectA.Id);
```

Note that the field name you supply to `putSobject()` is the relationship form. For custom objects, it's postfixed with `__r` (`__c` is an Id field). For standard objects, it's the name of the field without `Id` suffixed, so for `Contact.AccountId` you would do

```
someContact.putSobject('Account', someAccount);
```

Comment: I'll Update the question, one minute.

Comment: I just Updated!

Comment: @ekiim Thanks, I will come back in a few and see if I can be more specific.